# Does the solution to "The Shoe Store Thief" include the price of the shoes?

Tags: professor-layton-diabolical-box

In Professor Layton and the Diabolical Box, puzzle 20 (The Shoe Store Thief) involves a woman who uses a counterfeit $50 bill to buy a $30 pair of shoes. The puzzle asks how much money the shoe-store clerk lost in dollars.

Does the amount of money lost include the price of the $30 shoes? (Please don't include the puzzle solution unless you use a spoiler block. I'm only looking to clarify an ambiguous part of the question)

[image: Puzzle 20]

Comment: I fail to see why the price of the shoe matters. He made an equal exchange for 50 fake dollars, so he lost 50 dollars. That's it. The rest of the story doesn't matter. Would the story change if the shoes were on a discount? I don't think so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the price of the $30 shoes are included in the solution.

> The answer is $50. The shoes cost $30 and the change given to the customer was $20.
>
>  [image: solution]